# Issue plotting excel tables to multiple powerpoint slides

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have created a template on excel which is populated with data for a specific country. The template contains 3 tables and a chart (line graph). I have a list of countries that I need to loop through, and for each loop, I need to create a powerpoint slide made up of the 3 tables and chart.

I build the macro below using bits from various sources (mostly from this platform). The macros scales and positions each of the elements. The first slide populates correctly, but I am running into the following issues:

1. All the tables and charts are positioned correctly on the first slide, but are not being positioned on every other slide. Note that the objects are still being scaled correctly
2. I get Run-time error ‘-214788160 (80048240): Selection (unknown member) : Invalid request. This view does not support selection

Does anyone have any suggestions for what the issue could be?

```
Sub MulipleCountrySlides()
'Step 1: Declare your variables

  Dim ListOfSystems As Variant
  Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout

  Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim PPSlides As PowerPoint.Slides
  Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim SlideTitle As String

  Dim XLS_Out As Variant
  Dim shp As Object

  Dim chtObj As ChartObject
  Dim chtTop As Double
  Dim chtLeft As Double
  Dim chtWidth As Double
  Dim chtHeight As Double

'Step 2: Open PowerPoint and create new presentation
  Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
  Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Add
  PP.Visible = True

'Step 3: Add new slide as slide 1 and set focus to it
  PPPres.ApplyTemplate "C:\Users\yogeswaran saravanan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\blank.potx"

  ListOfSystems = Range("listofsystemstest")    'This is the list of systems that I will be looping through

  For y = LBound(ListOfSystems) To UBound(ListOfSystems)
   Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(y, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

   Worksheets("System output sheet").Range("j2").Value = ListOfSystems(y, 1)
   Sheets("Indexed data").Calculate
   ActiveSheet.Calculate
   If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then            ' Calculation takes a while to run
        DoEvents
   End If
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(y)

'The following arrays specify the regions/charts to be copied/pasted,
'the sizes/positions of these regions/charts, and the slide numbers corresponding
'to region/chart destinations

'Region/chart widths (Length/width ratios are preserved)
OWidth = Array(910, 450, 900, 465) '' 72px per Inch

OHeight = Array(400, 120, 33, 147)

'Horizontal positions on slides
OLeft = Array(22, 22, 22, 22)

'Vertical positions on slides
OTop = Array(100, 360, 504, 200)

'Regions and charts to be copied/pasted
XLS_Out = Array(Range("Countryslidetable"), _
                Range("Chartdeltas"), _
                Range("Countryfootnote"), _
                Worksheets("System output sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 1"))

'Region/Chart type: 1 corresponds to chart objects, 0 corresponds to regions
XLS_OutFormat = Array(0, 0, 0, 1)

'Loop through arrays and copy/paste regions and charts one at a time
For x = 0 To 3 'LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)

    'Copy Excel range/chart
    XLS_Out(x).Copy

    'Paste to PowerPoint
    If (XLS_OutFormat(x) = 0) Then
        'Paste an Excel range
        Set shp = PPPres.Slides(y).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteHTML)
    Else
       'Paste an Excel chart
        Set shp = PPPres.Slides(y).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteShape)
        shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
    End If

    'Change position/size of pasted regions/charts based on previously-defined arrays
    With PPPres.Slides(y)
        'shp.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        shp.Height = OHeight(x)
        shp.Width = OWidth(x)

        shp.Top = OTop(x)
        shp.Left = OLeft(x)
        shp.ZOrder msoSendToFront
    'End With

    If (XLS_OutFormat(x) = 0) Then
        If (x = 2) Then
            PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextEffect.FontSize = 10
            End If
        If (x = 0) Then
            'Set oShp = PPSlide.Shapes(1)
            'Set oShp = PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            Set oTbl = shp.Table
            For i = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
                 For J = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
                 'oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 11
                 oTbl.Cell(J, i).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 11
                 Next
           Next
           End If
    End If
     End With
Next x

'Step 6: Add the title to the slide
  SlideTitle = "Country Price Recommendations: " & Worksheets("System output sheet").Range("J2")
  PPPres.Slides(y).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

'Step 7: Memory Cleanup
  PP.Activate
  Next y
  Set PPSlide = Nothing

  Set PPPres = Nothing

  Set PP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you see the error?

Comment: What view are you in? If PPT is in a view that doesn't allow you to select a shape, then this will fail and give the error msg you report : PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextEffect.FontSize = 10  Same with anything that refers to .Selection.  Also, it's a good habit to add Option Explicit to the top of every module. That'll prevent you from using undeclared variables (x and y, in this case).

Comment: I think I'm in "Normal" view (sorry bit of a noob here). Any way I can check? Or rather, any way I can make sure I'm in a view that will allow me to select shapes?

Comment: ActiveWindow.ViewType will give you the current view type, and ActiveWindow.ViewType=9 will set it to Normal view. You can pick up the current viewtype, change it to Normal, then reset it to the original value later if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Steve. I've made sure that the ViewType = 9, but what actually seemed to fix it was adding  "PP.ActivePresentation.Slides(y).Select." I now have a new issue where the code runs for 5-6 loops before crashing with a "Automation error - remote procedure call failed."  The error occurs in the "Set shp = PPPres.Slides(y).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteHTML)" and "Set shp = PPPres.Slides(y).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteShape)."  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd search SO for Shapes.PasteSpecial .. a number of people have reported problems with this particular command; some have found workarounds/solutions.